# How to prevent keypad from hiding like whatsapp while click on send button and make continuous focus on edit text in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I want to prevent soft keypad from hiding from `edittext` while click on send button in my messaging app like in whatsapp while we click on send button but `softkeypad` does not disappear I have tried to `requestfocus` on `edit text` and showing keypad but it shakes keypad like it goes down and then come up. Please can any one help me regarding this issue.

Comment: you hide keyboard or disable edittext focus...

Comment: i want keypad to stay on screen while i press on send button

Comment: InputMethodManager inputMethodManager (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `onCreate`, it will forcely open softkeyboard-

```
 ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

To hide it, use below code-

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(_pay_box_helper.getWindowToken(), 0)
```

In your manifest-

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" ... />
```

Comment: I have tried your way but then keyboard hides after loses focus

Comment: also use `editText.requestFocus()` and `setFocusable(true)`.

Answer (score 1):

Give android:nextFocusDown to same EditText id.

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:imeOptions="actionSend"
                android:nextFocusDown="@id/loginPassword"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This method may help you

```
editext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (hasFocus) {

                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });
```